# VS2013 C++: Map - Unhandled Exception, Out of Range

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, visual-studio-2013, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to create a function that keeps track of recently used addresses, using a vector of maps for each index. Each time the address (used as the map key) is found, it would update the key member variable value. If its not a mapped value in the table, it will add it. That way I can keep track of older vs. newer addresses. Initially I tried to code it in the following manner:

```
int key = 0;
void update(uint32_t address, int index, vector<map<uint32_t, int> >& table)
{
    auto search = table.at(index).find(address);
    if(it != table.at(index).end())
    {
         table[index][address] = ++key;
    }
    else
    {
         table.at(index).insert(make_pair(address, ++key));
    }
}
```

However, every time I go to test my function, VS2013 always throws an unhandled exception error informing me that the `Unhandled exception` was thrown because `std::out_of_range` when it gets to the `auto search` line. I figured the error was thrown because the map starts off initially empty, and there are no maps available for it to search through for any addresses. So then I modified it to determine first if the table is empty, if so insert the first pair, otherwise if its not, search the table for the address value, and update the key:

```
int key = 0;
void update(uint32_t address, int index, vector<map<uint32_t, int> >& table)
{
    if(table.at(index).empty())
    {
        table.at(index).insert(make_pair(address, key));
    }
    else
    {
        auto search = table.at(index).find(address);
        if(it != table.at(index).end())
        {
             table[index][address] = ++key;
        }
        else
        {
             table.at(index).insert(make_pair(address, ++key));
        }
     }
}
```

But then the same exception occurs at the `if(table.at(index).empty())` line. Then I scaled it down, just to see if I could just simply capture and store any maps at all:

```
int key = 0;
void update(uint32_t address, int index, vector<map<uint32_t, int> >& table)
{
   table.at(index).insert(make_pair(address, ++key));
}
```

And that generates the same unhandled exception also at `table.at(index).insert(make_pair(address, ++key))`.

Not only that but I've tried determining if the `table.at(index) == NULL` or `nullptr` or `0`. Looked for alternative means of adding the map pairs to the vector, instead of using `insert`. Unfortunately, the options I was looking at don't exist for `map` (i.e. `assign` or `push_back`). I also looked into implementing a try-catch statement, but wasn't exactly sure on how to code it, especially with the "throw" keyword.

I have no idea what could be causing this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be the problem? Or what I'm doing wrong? Maybe my program doesn't like my vector of maps possibly?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't `index+1` entries in your vector and `.at()` is throwing the exception as a result. I.e. the map has nothing do to with this, since there isn't one in the first place. Stop looking at the map and debug your program, making sure you actually have `index+1` entries before trying to reference an entry in slot `index`.

Comment: You are checking whether the `map` is empty or not. Also check whether the `vector` has enough entries ( `index + 1` ) or not.

Comment: I did debug my program (I typically run it in debug mode to watch the variables step-by-step). It turns out that I was trying to index into an empty vector with no locations for it to look it. So I ended up initializing my table to the index length I need to support and it worked. So now when I want to look at an index location, the index exists for it to go to.